# Spring: beans using namespaces in IDs conflict with SPeL

Tags: java, spring, dependency-injection, spring-el

Dhanji in his [book about Dependnecy Injection](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/193398855X) encourages usage of namespaces when naming spring beans.

Qutation from the book:

> I also strongly encourage use of namespaces, for example, "set.BinaryTree" and 
>   "set.HashTable," which are nicer to read and comprehend than  "binaryTreeSet"
>   and "hashTableSet." Namespaces are a more elegant and natural nomenclature for 
>   your  key space and are eminently more readable than strings of grouped capitalized 
>   words.

Now that sounds reasonable. But as of [SPeL](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/expressions.html), the conflicts arises.
 Ozzy used to play in Black Sabbath, so for every band member I'll use **bs** namespance in bean name like so:

```
<bean id="bs.ozzy"
    class="sk.spring.idol.annotation.Instrumentalist" 
    p:song="Sabbath Bloody Sabbath" />
```

Now I have other member of black sabbath, who will have injected value for song name using SpEL. Whatever song that ozzy plays will also play my new member (let's say Tony):

```
public class Instrumentalist implements Performer {

@Value("#{bs.ozzy.song}")
private String song;

// blabla other stuff, getters setters and so on
```

}

Now what will I get is ...

```
Expression parsing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.expression.spel.SpelEvaluationException: EL1008E:(pos 0): Field or property 'bs' cannot be found on object
```

**Now what**? Is there some way to escape text as "this is bean name and don't evaluate this as property"?

Notes:

- The code sample is inspired by Dhanji's book.
- I confess - I haven't read the whole documentation for SpEL, maybe solution is much much simpler

Answer (score 1):

You can do this:

```
@Value("#{ #this.getObject('bs.ozzy').song }")
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if the context itself is exposed as a property/reference.

If it's not (still looking), you could just create a function that looks up a bean by name, so it'd look like this (more or less):

```
@Value("#{byId('bs.ozzy').song}")
```

Even if you could get a bean by id via a method or map lookup with a string key, I'm kind of "meh" about the idea, because you'd potentially lose some IDE functionality.

I think I'd prefer namespacing with an `_` (underscore). Using dots screws up most anything that expects dots to be a property separator/method call (which is a lot of stuff).

Comment: I agree, namespaces shouldn't be having "." as separator anymore if SPeL is used. But you know, we have pretty big codebase and now we either shouldn't use SPeL or rewrite the thing. :/